# Time machine not backing up my Home Folder

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I just started using Time Machine, and it appears to not be backing up my Home Folder.
I just went 'back in time' and clicked on the Home Folder icon and it said 0 files.
I need the things in my Home Folder to be backed up, because that is where everything is saved and secure.
What am I doing wrong.
In time machine the only thing that is excluded from backup is my removable hard-drive that I use for time machine backups.
Please help, I am not computer smart so please answer in "simple" works.
THANKS

Comment: Time Machine needs some time for the first backup. Are you sure a first backup was created at all? Did you check in the Time Machine preference pane if you maybe excluded your home folder? Do you use FileVault? (If so, Time Machine will back up your home folder only when logged out and will not show its content in the timeline.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using FileVault?  This is a known "issue" where Time Machine only backs up the sparsebundle that contains your FileVault home directory when you're logged out.  Even then, I'm not sure how well that works because it apparently backs up the entire thing each time, which leads me to believe restoring can only be an all-or-nothing deal.